# what should I do when requests.get(url) doesn't work?

Tags: python, python-requests

I just wanna get html using requests, but I can't.. this is the code.

```
import requests
from time import sleep 

url = 'https://www.wevity.com/'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36'}
html = ''

while html == '':
  try:
    html = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
  except:
    print('sleep 5sec..zz')
    sleep(5)
    continue

print(html.text)
```

first I faced the error, I added header(User-agent) and sleep() but it doesn't works.. console just printed sleep 5sec..zz and stoped

what should I do..?

Comment: Try to print the exception

Comment: Also try adding `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` in `headers`.

Comment: I ran your code as is, and it works perfectly. which environment are you using to run your program? Also, include the error message in your answer.

Comment: thanks guys
@RajibHossen I use repl.it. I will try it another environment! thanks